# Does the fiber product of two regular varieties over perfect field remain regular?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

k is a perfect field. X and Y are two regular varieties over k. Does their fiber product over k remain to be regular?

Note: When k is algebraically closed it's true by Jacobian criterion. When k is not perfect there's counter-example.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what's the counterexample?

Comment: Let the field be F_2(t). The two rings are A=F_2(t)[x,y]/(y^2+x^3+tx), B=F_2(t,s)/(s^2-t), which is actually a field.

Comment: The notion of smooth and regular coincides when the residue field of the point is perfect. It seems that the condition in the problem is not enough

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is yes. Indeed, over a perfect field the notions of smooth and regular coincide so it follows from the fact that base change and composition preserve smoothness.